# Stackoverflow on mobile layout

Tags: support, design, mobile-web

I just opened stackoverflow.com, and it appears in a mobile-like design.

I am opening it from Chrome on Windows 7.

Is this  a bug?

Comment: Click on 'full site' in the footer. You probably accidentally clicked the `mobile` link in the footer recently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load the mobile version in any browser, not just on a mobile platform, by clicking on the *mobile* link in the full site footer.

To get back to the full site (again, on any platform, even a mobile browser), click on the *full site* text in the mobile site footer.

This is a feature, not a bug. :-) You must've switched accidentally.

Answer (score 3):

Go to page bottom and there is a link of `meta chat about help blog privacy policy legal contact us full site` , from that click on `full site` and you can see it properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can access both the mobile site on desktop and the desktop site on mobile (I congratulate stack exchange for doing this!).

You can change between the two using the "mobile" or "full site" links at the bottom of the page (which you probably accidently clicked at some point.)

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Great paint skills! :D

Comment: @enb081 If it's not a [freehand red circle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/220332) you might was well not bother! The funny thing is that I actually use my very nice image editor for which I create game artwork